# Problems with Bootstrap Container on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm working on the responsive part of my website but I'm having a bug with the mobile devices. When I test the responsive on my desktop browser everything works great, but when I test on my iphone this is what happens.

screenshot #1 [image]
screenshot #3 [image: http://i.imgur.com/ebAhfdr.png]

I don't know why but the container apply some sort of margin in the right. Already searched everywhere and nothing's fixing it. Already changed the viewport and add a min-width to the body. This happens when I have a 100% width on the main div.

If someone can help me with this i would be very thankful, because i'm trying to fix this for days.

Comment: Do you have `html, body {width: 100%;}` in your css anywhere? If you don't, add it. It could be part of the issue.  Additionally, make sure you have a `viewport` meta tag in your head.

Comment: Looks like you might have something with a fixed width that's forcing the width of the page to be that big. Search through your CSS and see if you can find anything. Had the same sort of issue on my own site a while back, it was due to something being fixed width that I didn't realise was.

Comment: One technique I've used to track down things like @AndrewMatthew mentions is to put `html, body (width: 100%, overflow: hidden}` - this will "chop off" anything you've got set too-wide, and you can then see where you need to look for width issues.

Comment: I'm trying to search on my css. The problem is if i put the width of my desktop browser smaller everything work really well the problem is when i open on the iphone it appears that error.

Comment: Hi Aamir. The link for the website is this one. [link](https://www.songvice.com/experts/andivax). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally i fixed this problem. After a lot time trying different things I just wrote this css for all the small devices.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
html, body {
width: auto !important;
overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
}
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but solved my problem. I had this bug for a long time, i'm happy it's working now.

Thanks a lot everyone that tried to help me.
Cheers

Comment: This also solved my extra space appearing on mobile devices.